# Scrape websites using scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a [website](http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/) with scrapy but I am having problem with scraping the all products from this site as it is using endless scrolling...

I can scrape only below data for 52 items only but their are 3824 items.

```
hxs.select("//span[@class='itm-Catbrand strong']").extract()
hxs.select("//span[@class='itm-price ']").extract()
hxs.select("//span[@class='itm-title']").extract()
```

If I use `hxs.select("//div[@id='content']/div/div/div").extract()` Then it extracts whole items list but it won't filter further....How do I scrape all the items?

I have tried this but same result. Where am I wrong?

```
def parse(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body
    for n in [2,3,4,5,6]:            
    req = Request(url="http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/?page=" + n,
                      headers = {"Referer": "http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/",
                                 "X-Requested-With": response.header['X-Requested-With']})
    return req
```

Comment: I am not sure that `response.header['X-Requested-With']` equals "XMLHttpRequest", so the website may redirect you to (or serve) the original items page. Plus you should probably use `yield req` or put all requests in a list.

Comment: How to set Header that you mentioned earlier...and using yield/return i am getting this error `ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'Request' in <GET http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have guessed, this website uses javascript to load more items when you scroll the 
page.

Using the developers tools included in my browser (Ctrl-Maj i for chromium), I saw in the Network tab that the javascript script included in the page performs the following requests to load more items :

```
GET http://www.website-your-are-crawling.com/men/shoes/?page=2 # 2,3,4,5,6 etc...
```

The web server responds with documents of the following type :

```
<li id="PH969SH70HPTINDFAS" class="itm hasOverlay unit size1of4 ">
  <div id="qa-quick-view-btn" class="quickviewZoom itm-quickview ui-buttonQuickview l-absolute pos-t" title="Quick View" data-url ="phosphorus-Black-Moccasins-233629.html" data-sku="PH969SH70HPTINDFAS" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BadgeQV','Shown','OFFER INSIDE']);">Quick view</div>

                                    <div class="itm-qlInsert tooltip-qlist  highlightStar"
                     onclick="javascript:Rocket.QuickList.insert('PH969SH70HPTINDFAS', 'catalog');
                                             return false;" >
                                              <div class="starHrMsg">
                         <span class="starHrMsgArrow">&nbsp;</span>
                         Save for later                         </div>
                                        </div>
                <a id='cat_105_PH969SH70HPTINDFAS' class="itm-link sobrTxt" href="/phosphorus-Black-Moccasins-233629.html" 
                                    onclick="fireGaq('_trackEvent', 'Catalog to PDP', 'men--Shoes--Moccasins', 'PH969SH70HPTINDFAS--1699.00--', this),fireGaq('_trackEvent', 'BadgePDP','Shown','OFFER INSIDE', this);">
                    <span class="lazyImage">
                        <span style="width:176px;height:255px;" class="itm-imageWrapper itm-imageWrapper-PH969SH70HPTINDFAS" id="http://static4.jassets.com/p/Phosphorus-Black-Moccasins-6668-926332-1-catalog.jpg" itm-img-width="176" itm-img-height="255" itm-img-sprites="4">
                            <noscript><img src="http://static4.jassets.com/p/Phosphorus-Black-Moccasins-6668-926332-1-catalog.jpg" width="176" height="255" class="itm-img"></noscript>
                        </span>                            
                    </span>

                                            <span class="itm-budgeFlag offInside"><span class="flagBrdLeft"></span>OFFER INSIDE</span>                       
                                            <span class="itm-Catbrand strong">Phosphorus</span>
                    <span class="itm-title">
                                                                                Black Moccasins                        </span>
```

These documents contain more items.

So, to get the full list of items you will have to return `Request` objects in the `parse` method of your Spider (See the [Spider class documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.parse)), to tell scrapy that it should load more data :

```
def parse(self, response):
    # ... Extract items in the page using extractors
    n = number of the next "page" to parse
    # You get get n by using response.url, extracting the number
    # at the end and adding 1

    # It is VERY IMPORTANT to set the Referer and X-Requested-With headers
    # here because that's how the website detects if the request was made by javascript
    # or direcly by following a link.
    req = Request(url="http://www.website-your-are-crawling.com/men/shoes/?page=" + n,
       headers = {"Referer": "http://www.website-your-are-crawling.com/men/shoes/",
          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"})
    return req # and your items
```

Oh, and by the way (in case you want to test), you can't just load `http://www.website-your-are-crawling.com/men/shoes/?page=2` in your browser to see what it returns because the website will redirect you to the global page (ie `http://www.website-your-are-crawling.com/men/shoes/`) if the `X-Requested-With` header is different from `XMLHttpRequest`.